# Logging on a website with python + selenium+

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I have some problem getting the code to work. I want to **scrape** a website. So far I have used this :

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
wd.get('https://ma-mbp.ra.rockwell.com/mediabin/action/iw.ui')
time.sleep(25)
print(wd.page_source) # results
```

Output is always the same.
I am not able to do the logging.

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

I can select non element

Comment: The result is a <html><head></head><body></body></html>

Comment: what are you trying to achieve your inforation is not clear

Comment: Have you tried removing the headless option to check what the page looks like?

Comment: I want do a Scraping. But I need to be login first. I am trying to sent my credentials with selenium selector. Not because I have make some research apparently the Javascript. Make Hard to the find the tags. That I need for the logging its appaer empty when get the source code of the wedside